# If the height of the element with `container-type: size` become 0, what is the practical benefit of `container-type: size`?

Tags: html, css, container-queries

AFAIK The of container queries concept is the applying of the conditional CSS rules depending on *unknown at advance* container size. However, once `container-type: size` applied (what it required to make the container queries work), the height of the container become `0`. It is to like setup the thermometer in the room and *because of it* the temperature in the room has become constant 0 by Celsius - it sounds crazy but it exactly what I am feeling about height has become 0 because of  `container-type: size`.

## My case

I have the table and I want to conditionally display/hide the `.CalendarPage-DayCell-ScrollViewForLargeContainers` and `CalendarPage-DayCell-ButtonForSmallContainers`, herewith the "Large" and "Small" is not only width - it also the height.

```html
<td class="CalendarPage-DayCell">
    <div class="CalendarPage-DayCell-ContainerQueryProvider">
        <span class="CalendarPage-DayCell-Title">6</span>
        <div class="CalendarPage-DayCell-ScrollViewForLargeContainers">
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>
        <button class="CalendarPage-DayCell-ButtonForSmallContainers" type="button">
            <!-- ... -->
        </button>
    </div>
</td>
```

```css
.CalendarPage-DayCell-ContainerQueryProvider {
  container-type: size;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@container (max-width:99px) and (max-height:99px) {
  .CalendarPage-DayCell-ButtonForSmallContainers {
    background: #00f; /* Temporary styles for indication */
  }
}

@container (min-width:100px) and (min-height:100px) {
  .CalendarPage-DayCell-ButtonForSmallContainers {
    background: red; /* Temporary styles for indication */
  }
}
```

Initially I have added `container-type: size;` to the table cell (`td`) but looks like the container queries are incompatible with the table cell (please correct me if I am wrong).
That is why I have been forced to add the `.CalendarPage-DayCell-ContainerQueryProvider`. However, with `container-type: size` make its height to `0`:

[image]

Because the table is responsive, the height of cell and whole table is unknown at advance.

Comment: *what is the practical benefit of `container-type: size`?* --> only when the container is sized with something else than it's content (ex: a full screen height container). If your content is defining the height of the container (which is 80% of all the cases) simply forget about container-type: size.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you for the comment. I tried to assign `flex-grow: 1` to `.CalendarPage-DayCell-ContainerQueryProvider` and wrap it with one more element with `display: flex; flex-direction: column`. Even this did not work...

Comment: flex-grow on what? is the parent element where you will grow your element have an explicit height or is sized based on an upper element having an explicit height? adding extra wrapper won't solve the issue if your content is still defining the height, you will simply cascade your issue to another element

Comment: @TemaniAfif, "flex-grow on what?", on the newly added `div` element, the parent of ".CalendarPage-DayCell-ContainerQueryProvider". "is the parent element where you will grow your element have an explicit height or is sized based on an upper element having an explicit height?" - Of course, no. Here is the responsive design and "explicit height" is exactly what must not be in the responsive design (except small element). "adding extra wrapper won't solve the issue..." - too sad, what can I say... I expected more from the container queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Temani Afif said in the comments,

> What is the practical benefit of container-type: size? --> only when
> the container is sized with something else than it's content (ex: a
> full screen height container). If your content is defining the height
> of the container (which is 80% of all the cases) simply forget about
> container-type: size.

The query container has disappoint me again, but in my case, the `height: 100%` (not the `min-height: 100%`) for the `.CalendarPage-DayCell-ContainerQueryProvider` was the solution.

```css
.CalendarPage-DayCell-ContainerQueryProvider {
  container-type: size;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a minimum height:

```css
.CalendarPage-DayCell-ContainerQueryProvider {
  container-type: size;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 1px; /* or any value that suits your design */
}
```

*Additionally, consider specifying styles for the* `.CalendarPage-DayCell-ScrollViewForLargeContainers` *and* `.CalendarPage-DayCell-ButtonForSmallContainers` *elements to show or hide them based on the container size.*